# Google Apps isn't delivering mail to my lists

Tags: smtp, email

We host the email for our company with Google Apps, and we use email lists to deliver things to the engineering team (engineering@my_company.com).  We have automated exception emails that get sent out when there is an exception raised on a production server.

This has suddenly stopped working for me on my newest server.  The configuration is the same, but that particular server can't send to lists.  It can send email to individual users at my_company.com, but any list at my_company.com fails.  Google claim to be delivering the mail:

```
Jul  8 14:26:52 server_name postfix/smtp[16674]: 9857320000CF: to=<engineering@my_company.com>, orig_to=<deploy@server_name.my_company.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[209.85.210.37]:25, delay=1
, delays=0.62/0/0.13/0.29, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1247081212 3si22436256yxe.112)
```

But I never get the email.  It doesn't show up in the users' spam folders, and lists don't have a spam folder to check.

I've set the SPF records, but that seems unlikely to be the source of the problem, since I can send email to individual users.

The exact same configuration works fine on other servers.

Why is Google not delivering the email?  What can I do to get it delivered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely check the SPF records, that's how I solved the same problem.

Google Apps seems to pay special attention to e-mails that go to groups rather than mails that go to individuals.

Also check the new Google Apps groups feature: You need to enable the group ability to receive e-mail from any server:

https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/yourdomain.com/GroupSettings?groupId=yourgroup@yourdomain.com

Comment: @Michael-sofaer, was it an SPF indeed?